# API post issue with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im having an issue where I get a 404 error when posting to my route.

This is my code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Page= require('../models/page.js');
var adminUser= require('../models/admin-users.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser').json();
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
/* User Routes. */

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to the API zone');
});

router.get('/pages', function(request, response) {

        return Page.find(function(err, pages) {
            if (!err) {
                return response.send(pages);
            } else {
                return response.send(500, err);
            }
        });
    });

//Post method, creates new Page object 
router.post('/pages/add',bodyParser, sessionCheck, function(request, response) {


    var page = new Page({
        title: request.body.title,
        url: request.body.url,
        content: request.body.content,
        menuIndex: request.body.menuIndex,
        date: new Date(Date.now())
    });  

    page.save(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            return response.send(200, page);

        } else {
            return response.send(500,err);
        }
    });
});


router.post('/pages/update',bodyParser, sessionCheck, function(request, response) {
    var id = request.body._id;

    Page.update({
        _id: id
    }, {
        $set: {
            title: request.body.title,
            url: request.body.url,
            content: request.body.content,
            menuIndex: request.body.menuIndex,
            date: new Date(Date.now())
        }
    }).exec();
    response.send("Page updated");
});

// id rem
router.get('/pages/delete/:id', bodyParser, sessionCheck, function(request, response) {
    var id = request.params.id;
    Page.remove({
        _id: id
    }, function(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    });
    return response.send('Page id- ' + id + ' has been deleted');
});


// -----
router.get('/pages/admin-details/:id', bodyParser, sessionCheck, function(request, response) {
    var id = request.params.id;
    Page.findOne({
        _id: id
    }, function(err, page) {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
        return response.send(page);
    });
});

router.get('/pages/details/:url', function(request, response) {
    var url = request.params.url;
    Page.findOne({
        url: url
    }, function(err, page) {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
        return response.send(page);
    });
});


// 404 error

router.post('/add-user', function(request, response) {
    var salt, hash, password;
    password = request.body.password;
    salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

    var AdminUser = new adminUser({
        username: request.body.username,
        password: hash
    });
    AdminUser.save(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            return response.send('Admin User successfully created');

        } else {
            return response.send(err);
        }
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(request, response) {
  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.password;

  adminUser.findOne({
    username: username
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err | data === null) {
      return response.send(401, "User Doesn't exist");
    } else {
      var usr = data;

      if (username == usr.username && bcrypt.compareSync(password, usr.password)) {

        request.session.regenerate(function() {
          request.session.user = username;
          return response.send(username);

        });
      } else {
        return response.send(401, "Bad Username or Password");
      }
    }
  });
});

router.get('/logout', function(request, response) {
    request.session.destroy(function() {
        return response.send(401, 'User logged out');

    });
});

function sessionCheck(request,response,next){

    if(request.session.user) next();
        else response.send(401,'authorization failed');
}

module.exports = router;
```

The issue is with the `router.post('/add-user', function(request, response) {`

Is there any more information you need?

Also i Tried adding bodyparser `router.post('/add-user', bodyParser, function(request, response) {`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The one useful thing would be the code you have making the post. There's also the issue that it looks like no reference is made to `api.js` in `app,js` so I don't know how your router in `api.js` is getting attached to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing those lines :

```
var api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/', api);
```

I would even recommend you to do the following :

```
app.use('/api', api);

router.get('/', function(request, response)
router.get('/pages', function(request, response)
router.post('/pages/add', function(request, response)
```

That way, you won't have 2 different requests being redirected to the same route

Comment: technically, he'd want to do `app.use('/api',api);` or also remove `app.use('/', routes);` from app.js otherwise.

Comment: @krakig Hi there! Thanks this helped me, however, now I have a new issue, I get  Failed at the myproj@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www' After I added the: 


`var api = require('./routes/api');
app.use('/', api);`

EDIT: It fails when I add var api = require('./routes/api');

Comment: where is your api.js file located? maybe it's not in the correct foler

Comment: @krakig http://pokit.org/get/img/a6aa612a5895488590660746f1af6dc8.jpg Please look here, this is the folder structure.

Comment: @krakig http://pokit.org/get/img/fd898a3c10061dd6a4e755cb0960e119.jpg Please look here the output of the console, when i remove the require it is working again..

Comment: Are you sure you declared all the dependencies correctly? And check the path of the files you require to be sure they are correct

Comment: @krakig dude, I was missing a dependency in api.js not in app.js I did install depcheck and found out that it was missing, sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you very much!!